# Tiling a triangular grid using a specific pattern

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of Triangle objects that are equilateral triangles and have for x and y coordinates the center of the triangle :

[image]

The distance between this point and a, b or c is `t_r`.
The distance between this point and A, B or C is `t_R`.
The side of a triangle is `t_size`

I want to create a function that place each triangle on a grid following this order :

[image]

So this function gets the index of the triangle in the array and updates its x and y position.
Do you have any idea how I could proceed ?
You should note that when the triangles are upside down, their center point is still as if they were straight but I just draw them inverted.
For example, the translation from the first triangle to the second isn't up and right but only right.

I really don't know how I could do this. I tried to find a pattern in each "level" (color) of triangles but I didn't find any, neither in the side where the next triangle will be that change for every triangle...

Comment: What problem are you facing, what have you tried so far?

Comment: But center of triangle 2 is higher by `t_R/2` (one third of the height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems relatively straightforward. There is a limited number of jumps needed to go from one step to the next, and they are quite predictable too.

Let us enumerate the different jumps:

- 1 to 2 (also found in 8 to 9, or reversed in 4 to 5): (t_size * cos(30º), t_size * sin(30º))
- 2 to 3 (or any other vertical-up): (0, t_size)
- 3 to 4 (a reflection of 1 to 2): ( - t_size * cos(30º), t_size * sin(30º) )
- 4 to 5 (left as an exercise)
- 5 to 6 (another exercise)
- 6 to 7 (as in moving from 4 to 2; therefore = - (d12 + d23 + d34), where dXY is the vector used to move from X to Y)
- 6 to 1 = -d34

Now, let us continue the sequence using these displacements:

- first ring: d12, d23, d34, d45, d56,
- jump to next ring: d67
- second ring: d61, d12, d23, **d12, d23**, d34, **d23, d34**, d45, **d34, d45**, d56, **d45, d56**, d61, **d56, d61**
- jump to next: d67

In the next ring, you would extend the bolded segments (the "do a zigzag in this direction) to repeat them thrice, and in the n-th ring, you would extend them n times.